# Define required modules hosted on git repo

Tags: perl, perl-module

I host my private (not shared on CPAN) perl modules at [gitlab.com](https://gitlab.com), so I can install them on remote hosts by running command: `cpanm https://gitlab.com/xxx/My-Module.git`. It works fine. But what if my private module, have in dependencies some other private modules? `Build.PL` like this:

```
use Module::Build;
Module::Build->new(
    module_name   => 'My::Module',
    dist_abstract => '-',
    requires      =>
    {
        'My::OtherModule' => 0,
        'Moo'             => 0,
    }
)->create_build_script;
```

Is there any way to declare GIT url for the `My::OtherModule`?

Comment: have you looked at MyConfig.pm or the used "o conf" command in the CPAN Shell? "perl -MCPAN -e shell" That is how you can declare repo URLs. I think this is what you want. Otherwise, more info please.

Comment: As I understand, you're talking about CPAN-like (private, self-hosted) repos. Im asking about GIT repos, like gitlab.com, github.com, etc.

Comment: Last time I tried to do this, cpanm could install from git but not handle git dependencies (since the CPAN metadata simply doesn't support this). The best solution I've found so far that doesn't require extra tooling (pinto, personal repositories, …) is to list all dependencies/git urls one item per line as a `requirements.txt` file, then install deps via `cpanm <requirements.txt`.

Comment: Those parameters are used to create a META file for CPAN. It makes no sense to mention private modules in a CPAN META file.

Comment: @ikegami: you're absolutely right. But this "META file for CPAN" is required by `cpanm` to successfully install a module from a non-CPAN location - like GIT repo. Its just that its super easy to just do `cpanm git@gitlab.com:user/My-Module.git` and have this module downloaded, builded, tested and installed. It simple, it works. Well, at least as long as these non-CPAN module doesnt require other non-CPAN modules ;).